# Custom Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, plugins, pde

I am a student, and I am currently working on a project to develop a plugin editor for Eclipse using Java 1.7. So far, I have successfully implemented the syntax coloring feature. To test my plugin, I exported it as a deployable Plugin JAR File. I copied the JAR File into the plugins folder of my Eclipse, restarted Eclipse, and was able to use my editor, and it worked correctly.

However, when I sent the JAR File to a friend for testing, and he followed the same steps, he could open the editor, but the syntax coloring did not work for him.

Does anyone have an idea why I am experiencing this issue?

Comment: Just putting a plugin in the plugins directory has not been supported as a way of installing for a long time now - a proper installable or using the 'dropins' folder is required. You should also update the version number each time as well.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you running?  What version of Eclipse is your friend running?  What version of Java is your friend running?  What version of Java are you running?